# Unicode variable labels

Tags: unicode, stata

I have a dataset but its variable labels are in unicode like this:

[image]

I tried typing:

```
unicode
```

However, this simply displays the following:

[image]

How can I correctly display the unicode?

Or, at least, is there any method I can see the labels using another program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data are in a file `data.dta` in your working directory (where Stata should point):

```
clear
unicode encoding set euc-kr
unicode translate data.dta
```

Type `help encodings` from Stata's command prompt for details regarding the different formats.

Comment: Thank you. But it still doesn't work. I tried your suggestion. But it says this: http://prntscr.com/js8ikg. So I tried `unicode translate data.dta, transutf8` But this also displays the same error. The label is probably written in CJK. What should I do for this?

Comment: Try this first: `unicode analyze data.dta` and see what it says.

Comment: Thank you again. I did it and it simply says this file needs translation. Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/js92fq

Comment: Type `unicode encoding set UTF-8 ` and then `unicode translate data.dta`

Comment: Thank you again. Now it runs something at least. But now it says things are nonconvertible. Screenshot:http://prntscr.com/js9at9

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/163EFKSzFj9ZRpMg2sQiGFyOchfOrn6y6/view?usp=sharing
This is a completely empty dataset with just one variable. Could you please check what's going wrong?

Comment: With this very tiny (empty) dataset, I ran your suggestions again, and I get the same errors. Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/js9cc3

Comment: What is your encoding? You must know the encoding.

Comment: Encoding is something different. Before you translate as above you need to set the correct encoding. Type `help encodings` for info.

Comment: Try `unicode encoding set UTF-16`. Looks like the output is an Asian language. I do not speak Korean.

Comment: I did 
`unicode encoding set euc-kr` and
`unicode translate *.dta, transutf8 invalid(ignore)`
and it worked! Thanks!